# How singletons are supposed to behave when different versions of same assembly are loaded?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose there is a singleton class in an assembly named `Common`. This DLL is used by my main application and a different version could be used by a plugin DLL in a plugins folder.

The distribution looks like this:

`\App.exe`

`\Common.dll (v1)`

`\Plugins\Plugin.dll`

`\Plugins\Common.dll (v2)`

So code in both `App` and `Plugin` are using that singleton class. I'm facing a hard to trace error which makes me think that somehow sometimes that singleton class loses all of its properties' values and starts to act like it's a new instance. From the stack trace, this always happens when it is being accessed by the plugin DLL.

EDIT: I just found some stack traces where it was being accessed by App. So cancel the last line of above paragraph.

Both `App` and `Plugin` (different VS projects) are compiled and linked with references added to their respective `Common` DLL versions.

EDIT: `Plugin` is loaded using `Assembly.LoadFrom` in the main AppDomain.

EDIT: `Common` DLL v2 present in Plugins folder also gets loaded dynamically with the `Plugin` DLL since all DLLs are being loaded from that folder:

`foreach( string extensionFile in Directory.GetFiles( ExtensionsDirectory, "*.dll" ) )`

Could anyone help what's going on?

Comment: I would assume that you're loading your `Plugin.dll` dynamically - how is it being loaded?

Comment: Looks plugin is loaded in its own process space hence is creates a new instance of class supposed to be a singleton. The application and plugin looks to be loaded as different process hence you will need some some mediator /third channel(through xml or WCF or any that fits in your situations) to share data instead depending on a singleton class.

Comment: I do not believe that the .NET Framework would allow you to load different versions of the same DLL.  It should result in ambiguity error since there will be several similar classes...

Comment: @DanPuzey Yes, Plugin is being loaded dynamically.

Comment: @platon I did a PoC on this. Plugin always uses the Common present alongside it and App always uses Common present alongside it.

Comment: @user1004959: *how* is it being loaded?

Comment: @user1004959: Into a separate AppDomain, or into the same AppDomain as the main assembly?  (Hint: post code!)

Comment: @DanPuzey Same AppDomain. `Assembly extensionAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( extensionFile );`

Comment: Then I think your singleton will probably be behaving you'd expect a singleton to behave.  (@platon explains why.)  What is the error you're struggling to trace?

Comment: @platon Why don't I get some ambiguity exception if that's the case?

Comment: @DanPuzey You mean the errors are expected? The errors are mostly null reference exceptions because a static collection which is supposed to have some data no longer has it.

Comment: @user1004959: if an assembly that `Plugin` relies on is already loaded, .NET *won't* try to reload the second copy of that assembly; it'll use the one already in memory.  To prove this either way: put a static constructor in your static class, and set a breakpoint in that constructor (or do something else that you can easily identify & count during runtime).

Comment: @DanPuzey I have a class in v2 which is not present in v1 and it is being used by Plugin and it works. How is that happening then? :)

Comment: @DanPuzey Even a new method in v2 in an existing class from v1 works when it is used by Plugin.

Comment: @DanPuzey Just found out that `Common` DLL v2 present in Plugins folder also gets loaded dynamically with the `Plugin` DLL since all DLLs are being loaded from that folder. `foreach( string extensionFile in Directory.GetFiles( ExtensionsDirectory, "*.dll" ) )`

Comment: I have no idea how it's happening, but it's clear that I don't have enough information from your question to be able to help.  I'd suggest you post more code, more substantiation information, or the results of the suggestion that I made (static constructor).  Are you saying that Plugin v1 and v2 are different projects entirely?  If they're not, are you sure you're building them separately and that v2 isn't being built to where you think v1 is?  *Something* you are doing hasn't been explained yet.  I can't tell you how it's happening by magic; *you have to share everything*.

Comment: @user1004959: Update your question (NOT in a comment) with the *entirety* of the code that is loading the assemblies (not individual lines that don't reveal the full behaviour).  Then I might be able to comment usefully.

Comment: @DanPuzey OK. v1 and v2 are same project. v2 is just a newer version with newer and/or modified code and increased assembly version attribute. I did a PoC some time ago on this situation. Let me find those and upload the projects somewhere.

Comment: So, it is possible, but Microsoft recomends *not* loading two versions of a DLL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#avoid_loading_multiple_versions

Comment: @DanPuzey "More subtle errors can occur if the behavior of the type changed between versions. For example, a method might throw an unexpected exception or return an unexpected value." Looks like I'd have to use multiple AppDomains. Thanks for your time. If you can post an answer, I'll mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible, Microsoft recomends *not* loading two versions of the same DLL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#avoid_loading_multiple_versions